# What are some (interesting) exceptions to the German grammar rules?

Tags: standard-german, grammaticality

I came across the description of one exception on [babbel.com](https://www.babbel.com/german-grammar):

> One of the only exceptions in common use came into being in the late
>   1960s, and that is substituting the pronoun “sie,” which means she,
>   for “es,” which means it, when discussing female children. The
>   difficulty arose from the German rule which classifies all German
>   nouns ending in “-lein” and “-chen,” both of which are diminutives, as
>   neuter. Including the neuter definite article, the German noun for
>   young girl is “das Mädchen”; therefore, German language authorities
>   enacted the change so that people could address young girls in the
>   third person using she.

The above paragraph seems to suggest that there are a few other rarer exceptions. **What are these?**

Some of the other exceptions that I know of are:

1) Some German nouns do not have a gender (e.g. Jura, meaning "Rechtswissenschaft als Studienfach"; Sanitär). I was asking a [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28012/are-there-any-german-nouns-that-do-not-have-a-gender) about this earlier. This is not an official exception, but *de facto*, it is.

2) There is a [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8853/why-die-nacht-but-des-nachts) on German Stack Exchange that asks if “des Nachts” is the correct Genitive of the noun “die Nacht”. Ultimately, it turns out that it actually is. Notes in [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=des%20Nachts) indicate that the use of "des Nachts" is *gehoben* or *veraltet*. It would be very interesting to learn of other nouns that inflect in certain cases (Akk.; Dat. Gen.) as if they were of a different gender.

3) Mark Twain notes in his 1880 book *A Tramp Abroad* that the phrase “wegen des Regens” is correct. He adds, however, the following:

> N. B. -- I was informed, later, by a higher authority, that there was
>   an "exception" which permits one to say "wegen **dem** Regen" in certain
>   peculiar and complex circumstances, but that this exception is not
>   extended to anything **but** rain.

According to [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=wegen), using Dative nowadays after *wegen* is not an exception, but rather a colloquial form of expression. Again, it would be very interesting to learn of a real non-colloquial exception, similar to the one above, valid in our days.

4) As can be seen from an answer to this [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32090/can-the-noun-name-be-without-n-ending-in-the-dative-case) of mine, the preposition *von* is not always followed by a noun in the dative case. As it turns out, in some cases it can be followed by a noun in the nominative case!

5) Of all the letters in the German alphabet, only one exists exclusively in the [lower-case-letter version](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf): ß

6) *The Hague* (a city in the Netherlands) in English = *Den Haag* in German. As far as I know, city-names in German are either masculine or neuter, used in the nominative case. But *Den Haag* is used in the accusative case.

Comment: There are no nouns without gender. Jura is male when you mean the Swiss canton, and it is a plurelatantum (a word that has no singular) when you mean Jurisprudence. At a pluraletantum the grammatical gender doesn't matter, because gender is only relevant in singular (which does not exist here). Also *Ferien*, *Eltern* and *Leute* are such words. And »sanitär« is not a noun (but an adjective) and therefore - like all adjectives - has no gender.

Comment: Other words that have no singular are: Gebrüder, Weihnachten, Gezeiten, Spaghetti, Spätzle, Faxen, Kinkerlitzchen, Unkosten, Möpse (if you mean female breasts), Flitterwochen, Naturalien, Noten (if you mean musical scores), Alimente, Manieren, and many more. So they are not really rare. And the rule says only, that all nouns that you can use in singular must have a gender (because you need gender only in singular), and there is no exception from this rule.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast With regard to "Sa­ni­tär", Duden states it's "Substantiv ohne Artikel". Usage example: "die Bereiche Sanitär, Heizung und Klima". Also according to Duden, Jura, as used to mean "Rechtswissenschaft als Studienfach", is also "Substantiv ohne Artikel". Examples of other similar words are: East, Reiß­aus, Google, and other: http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Substantiv%20ohne%20Artikel

Comment: The genitive of "die Nacht" is "der Nacht" ("Nacht" is a noun here.). On the other hand, "Nachts" in "des Nachts" is a nominalized abverb, coming from the abverb "nachts". It's definitely not colloquial.

Comment: I modified the wording of the question in response to comments about "des Nachts" by Xaver and @Jan. Looks like "des Nachts" belongs to the family of similar expressions starting with "des", such as: des Öfteren = many a time; des Weiteren = furthermore.

Comment: To point  3) you might want to see http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/wegen-genitiv-dativ.php

Comment: @HubertSchölnast some of your examples have a singular form: das Weihnachten, die Spaghetti. At least in German German according to Duden. Even with die Noten I would say that although Duden states it is a "Pluraletantum", anyone out on the street (or on the internet ;-) would think it's simply the plural of Note.

Comment: @Raketenolli. Widerspruch: *Die Weihnachten* gibt es nur im Plural (immerhin sind es mehrere Nächte/Nachten). Der Singular der Spaghetti ist »spaghetto«, aber das ist italienisch. Im Deutschen gibt es nur den Plural. Und die Noten, als Heft oder Buch, in dem ein Musikstück wiedergegeben wird, wird auch dann als Plural verwendet, wenn man nur ein Heft in der Hand hat. Eine einzelne Note ist etwas anderes.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast ich nehme stark an dass es sich hier um regionale Unterschiede handelt. In Südniedersachsen hat meiner Erfahrung nach niemand ein Problem damit "dieses Weihnachten" zu sagen, wenn er das kommende Weihnachten meint. "die Weihnachten" ist schlicht der Plural davon. Ebenso bin ich in der Lage, "eine Spaghetti" mit meiner Gabel aufzunehmen, also genau eine Nudel, und jeder hier fände das in Ordnung. Der Duden bestätigt diese beiden Verwendungen. Daher auch der Hinweis auf "German German" in meinem Kommentar. Könnte in Österreich anders sein.

Comment: @Raketenolli: Ich habe auch kein Problem damit »diese Weihnachten« zu sagen, weil das noch immer Plural ist, gleich wie »diese Feiertage«.

Comment: Die Frage solle als zu breit geschlossen werden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Im Deutschen gibt es zwar die Spaghetti als Pluralwort, aber man kann auch (wie Raketenolli auch weiß) eine Spaghetti aufstechen  und dann – jetzt wo wir die Spaghetti im Singular haben – mehrere Spaghettis essen. Das ist bei Spaghetti vielleicht ungewöhnlich, bei Gnocchi und anderen scheinbaren Pluralwörtern kann man das aber im ganz normalen Sprachgebrauch feststellen.

Comment: I wonder who these "German language authorities" are who, according to that site where they do not even know how to type an "ä", enacted a change in German grammar.

Comment: Yes, that's unclear about the authorities. But is the claim in the passage at all true?

Comment: @EugeneStr. I realize that you awarded the bounty to my answer. However, I looked at your blog and it seems like you know about this exception very well! I'm sorry about that!

Comment: @Skeleton Bow In my opinion, your answer is the best to this question. So, bounty rightfully deserved.

Comment: Hello again! Maybe this is a bit off-topic, but I happened to be browsing really old posts in an obscure Google Groups forum, and came across [this comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/alt.usage.german/nCMaMrAeBrA/oUpoXp7O_PMJ). For some reason it sounded very familiar... and that's because it was! Your blog looks different now but I still could recognize it. Thought it was interesting :)

Comment: I know it's been a while...but I'd say example 6) is not correct _Den Haag_ is just the/a Dutch name of that city. This has nothing to do with German _Akkusativ_.

Comment: With respect to 5): The capital version of the letter ß exists since 2008 as a Unicode character according to ISO/IEC 10646 and since 2017 it's formally part of the German language (see [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Großes_ß)).

Answer (score 3):

I've always found it interesting that some nouns (though rarely) can have two, and even three genders. Nouns with two genders aren't *that* uncommon, but ones with three genders are quite rare. One example is *Joghurt*. That means one can say all three of these:

- Der Joghurt
- Die Joghurt
- Das Joghurt

According to [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=joghurt), *der* is used normally, *das* is used in Austria, Switzerland and Southern Germany and *die* is used mainly in Austria.

According to [the Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/die-verteilung-der-artikel-genusangabe-im-rechtschreibduden), 98.7% of nouns have one article, 1.3% can be used with two (though the second one is usually regionally restricted or incorrectly used), and 0.02% can be used with all three articles. That's about one in every 5,000. Joghurt is one of them! Less than 0.1% have no articles.

Comment: @c.p. It says it here in the article: "*Einige wenige Substantive werden auch artikellos gebraucht, z. B. »Aids«, »Allerheiligen« oder »Donnerlittchen «. Sie machen im Rechtschreibduden weniger als 0,1 % aus.*"

Answer (score 1):

Countries, which take **das** article, can be used without their article if they do not have any adjective.

For example, without any adjective, it can be said

> **Ich komme aus Deutschland**

but if there is an adjective, it should be used with its article

> **Ich komme aus dem schönen Deutschland**

In contrast to the countries with **das** article, the countries with an article except for **das** are not affected from this and always be used with their articles.

**DIE** : die Schweiz, die Türkei

**DIE (Plural)**: die Vereinigten Staaten (the United States), die USA, die Niederlande

**DER**: der Irak, der Libanon, der Sudan

Comment: Most countries actually *can have* an article, you just don't see it very often - simply consider "Frankreich ist ein Land in Europa" vs. "das Frankreich der 20er Jahre ist heute noch berühmt für seinen Glamour" - And note this works with any country.

Comment: Ausnahmslos ALLE Staaten haben Artikel. Weiblich: Die Slovakei, die Mongolei, die Schweiz, die Türkei und einige mehr. Männlich: Der Kosovo, der Vatikan, der Kongo, der Jemen, der Sudan (auch diese Liste ist unvollständig). Plural: Die USA, die Niederlande, die Philippinen, die Seychellen und andere. Die meisten anderen Länder sind sächlich, was vor allen auffällt, wenn man zwischen Artikel und Land ein Attribut stellt: das schöne Österreich, das wiedervereinigte Deutschland, das alte China, das grüne Kanada, das riesige Russland, ...

Comment: @AdInfinitum in dem Artikel wird genau das Verhalten beschrieben, welches Hubert anmerkt. Das Phänomen, dass auch bei einigen nicht-sächlichen Ländernamen der Artikel manchmal weggelassen wird, ist ja noch neu und etwas irritierend (und würde beim Einsatz von Adjektiven auch übergangen)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast und Chieron, ich habe meine Antwort mit eueren Vorschlägen verbessert. Ist sie jetzt besser?

Comment: @AdInfinitum: Du bist jetzt zwar näher an der Wahrheit dran, aber leider auch weiter von dem weg, was gefragt war: Interessante Ausnahmen. Deine Antwort beschreibt aber keine Ausnahmen, sondern eine Regel.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast ich denke nicht, dass es eine Regel ist. Dann, was ist eine Ausnahme? %99.99 nehmen die Namen einen Artikel. in so einem speziellen Fall (ich nehme es als eine Ausnahme an), kann man ohne Artikel benutzen.

Comment: Wie? Willst du sagen, dass Namen in 99,99% aller Fälle mit Artikel verwendet werden? Willst du das Karl oder Lisa erklären? Hast du darüber schon mit Herrn Müller gesprochen? (»Karl«, »Lisa« und »Herr Müller« sind Namen, und ich habe sie, ohne einen Fehler zu machen, ohne Artikel verwendet!) Man das aber auch *dem* Karl und *der* Lisa erklären, und auch mit *dem* Herrn Müller darüber sprechen.

Comment: Du hast Recht aber dann, genau das Gegenteil ist eine Ausnahme. Ich meine Ich habe sowas nie gehört. z.B »Oliver« muss immer **das** als Artikel nehmen und egal wo man benutzt, muss sein Artikel immer dabei sein. In meiner Antwort, die Ausnahme ist, alle Länder haben einen Artikel aber wenn der Artikel **das** ist, muss man es nicht unbedingt benutzen aber in den anderen Fällen **muss** man den Artikel benutzen. Wenn **Ich komme aus Östrreich** erlaubt ist, ist **ich komme aus Schweiz** nicht. Es ist die Ausnahme.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Das stimmt nicht. Länder haben in der Regel keinen Artikel und sind Eigennamen im Neutrum. Wenn sie nicht im Neutrum stehen, dann kommt dieses Genus aus dem Verstand und nicht aus dem Sprachzentrum (der Jemen, die Schweiz). Bei Ländern auf -ei bin ich mir nicht sicher, weil viele normale Menschen arglos davon sprechen, dass sie nach Tschechei oder nach Türkei fahren. Man merkt ihnen dann vielleicht fehlende Bildung an, aber Bildung ist nie ein Kriterium für korrekten Sprachgebrauch.

Answer (score 0):

The answer regarding articles and countries reminded me of another, systematic exception concerning the use of articles: whenever there is talk of 'stations' or 'stops' (e.g., bus stops), articles are obligatorily absent. For example

> Du steigst **Hauptstraße** ein und steigst dann **Zoo** wieder aus.

If you would use a preposition like *am* in above sentence, it would not mean that you're not talking about a stop; instead, '*Ich steige **am Zoo** aus*' would mean that you leave the transportation in the vicinity of a zoo.

BTW This is not to confuse with instances of Kiezdeutsch as in *Ich geh **Aldi***. It's a German-wide feature as far as I know.

Comment: In Wien, in einer U-Bahn mitgehörtes Handy-Telefonat: »Wo bist du? Ich bin Stephansplatz. Gehst du heute auch Kino?«

Comment: Accordingly, there is no declination: "Ich steige _Grüner Weg_ aus".

Comment: This is nothing special, it's just shortening *an der Haltestelle* ***"Hauptstraße"***  to the *name* of that station. *Ich steige **am Zoo** aus* would work just as well, if the station is still unambigous, the station can identified by its *description*.

Comment: Didn't look at it that way yet. Please downvote, then.

Comment: @aslakr, you said _it would not mean that you're not talking about a stop_ – but did you mean _it would mean..._ (without the first _not_)?

Answer (score -1):

I think one special (or "funny") occurance, though not a rule, is that "mit" (with) is built with Dativ, while ohne (without) is used with Akkusativ.

Comment: How is this an exception?

Comment: In Austria you use ›ohne‹ with Dativ if you speak naturally. If you think you're an educated genius but in fact you aren't you use Akkusativ.

Answer (score -1):

Most modern dictionaries classify "nachts" as an adverb. Historically it is "ein adverbiell erstarrter Genitiv, gebildet in Analogie zu ... tags"  (DWDS).

Another example of a feminine noun having a masculine-type genitive is in compounds like “Universitätsprofessor”, with -s- by analogy to words like “Ratskeller”.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please notice, however, that I actually was asking about exceptions in addition to the ones I've  listed.

Comment: Fair enough. I have added a second example.

Comment: *Universitätsprofessor* is an example of a *Fugenlaut* (interfix). It does not have anything to do with the genitive, except maybe deriving from a genitive form centuries ago.

Comment: @Jan. Yes, centuries ago. Exactly my point. That is what we call etymology.

Comment: If you don’t say etymology, I have no way to magically know you are talking about it. In any way, etymology is not a subject of these questions, and interfixes are no longer perceived as genitives, so stating an etymology misses the question.

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't spent your lifetime searching for rare exceptions in German grammar. Cause if you find one some guy who knows historical linguistics can explain to you that it's no exception at all but a strict grammatical rule people don't see.

I wouldn't search for them on the basis of this text. ›One of the only exceptions‹ is an expression you just use without really thinking about it.

I also don't know what German language authorities should be. If you've read GG Art. 5 you know that such things don't exist and if they exist they're illegal.

---

To show you what I mean with no exceptions:

– Every German noun has a grammatical gender. A word without gender is as impossible as a human without sex. The standard human is the woman and the standard noun is the masculine. Humans can have two or more genders but not zero. ›Jura‹ has a gender, it's neuter:

> Dieses blöde Jura schon wieder!

– wegen: That's a whole story on its own. The short version: The genitive cannot be taken by a preposition because the preposition is a grammatical connection and the genitive is one, too. ›Wegen‹ is right with dative.

You can do that with every single one of your exceptions (with the pronouns, too) if you've got the time for it.

Comment: no. there are lot of words without gender.

Comment: **This** should be the answer to the question! The examples may not appeal to everybody but otherwise it’s the truest of statements.

Comment: @c.p. Tell me one and I'll believe you.

Comment: @deponensvogel Duden says: "Die meisten deutschen Substantive werden von einem Artikel begleitet, zum Beispiel »der Bumerang « (maskulin), »die Untersuchung« (feminin) oder »das Gewinnspiel« (neutral). Einige wenige Substantive werden auch artikellos gebraucht, z. B. »Aids«, »Allerheiligen« oder »Donnerlittchen «. Sie machen im Rechtschreibduden weniger als 0,1 % aus." The article in Duden is called: "Die Verteilung der Artikel (Genusangabe) im Rechtschreibduden". Link: http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/die-verteilung-der-artikel-genusangabe-im-rechtschreibduden

Comment: @Jan I don't see true in the examples. I don't think it is about perception.

Comment: @EugeneStr. The lack of an article does not signify the lack of a word’s gender.

Comment: @Jan That's what I thought. But which gender does *Allerheiligen* have?

Comment: @c.p. Names, i.e. proper nouns, don’t always follow the grammar rules of common nouns.

Comment: @c.p. ›Allerheiligen‹ is neuter. You can do the test: Das ist _das_ schönste Allerheiligen aller Zeiten!

Comment: It's not my mother tongue. I'm rather skeptic, for some of the other statements (linguistic related or not) are sort of fishy. Like humans having more than two genders and masculine being the standard gender of German nouns.