# Can the noun ‘Name’ be without ‘-n’ ending in the dative case?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, noun

According to [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Name_Ruf_Benennung_Bezeichnung), the singular dative of *Name* is *Namen*. However, in the below paragraph from the *Süddeutsche Zeitung* article "[Frauen mit Kopftuch müssen viermal so viele Bewerbungen schreiben](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/karriere/diskriminierung-bewerberinnen-mit-kopftuch-werden-bei-der-jobsuche-benachteiligt-1.3170492)", it's written *aufgrund von Name*. Is this a mistake or an exception of some sort?

> Immer wieder müssen sich Musliminnen, die Kopftuch tragen, gegen Verbote und Hindernisse im Beruf wehren. Eine Frau, der offensichtlich wegen eines religiösen Symbols eine Anstellung verweigert wird, kann wegen Diskriminierung klagen. **Was kann sie aber tun, wenn sie aufgrund *von Name* und Aussehen erst gar nicht für eine Stelle in Betracht gezogen wird?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that *Namen* is the dative case of *Name* and that *von* typically governs dative.

However, your example is an exception. Note that it says *aufgrund vo**n** Name und Aussehen* — there is no definite article, the phrase only has a null article. This is basically an *Ersatznominativ,* a replacing nominative case because no further modifiers are present. As soon as you add an additional modifier, this collapses:

> Wenn sie aufgrund von ihrem Namen und ihrem Aussehen … (possessive pronoun)
>
> Wenn sie aufgrund von ausländischem Namen und Aussehen … (adjective)
>
> Wenn sie aufgrund vom Namen und dem Aussehen … (article)

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for clarification! Is this an exception of the magnitude of "des Nachts” or German nouns without gender (like "Jura", meaning "Rechtswissenschaft als Studienfach", or "Sanitär")? Or is "Ersatznominativ" rather widespread in German?

Comment: @EugeneStr. I’ll have to pass on that one, sorry. My guess is rather widespread.

Comment: Google gives zero search results for "Ersatznominativ".

Comment: @Eller: [Canoo](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Genitiv.html#Anchor-Allein-49575) has the rule, but doesn't call it "Ersatznominativ".

Comment: M.E. ist das alles Genitiv: Wenn sie aufgrund ihres Namens und ihres Aussehens/ aufgrund des ausländischen Namens/aufgrund des Namens.

Comment: @userunknown Dein Beispiel ist Genitiv, ja. Nur ist das ein anderer Satz.

Comment: @userunknown *aufgrund <wessen>* steht mit Genitiv. Das stimmt. Aber heißt eben nicht *aufgrund von <wessen>*. Das sind unterschiedliche Konstruktionen.

Comment: @Jan Possibly another case of "Ersatznominativ": "An verschiedenen Stellen der Stadt soll es im Lauf des Abends zu Randale und Plünderungen gekommen sein, berichtet der TV-Sender CNN." "Randale" should be plural here, as I understand it from context. And, therefore, be "Randalen", which is the correct form for the dative case to be used after "zu".

Comment: @EugeneStr. Nope, that is a case of misprint or use of dialect. (Bavarian dialect actually uses an accusative form — consistently — for that construction.) While I can construct the argument to make the original question’s sentence okay (not stylistically great; just okay), leaving out the *n* of *Randalen* is wrong in standard German.